# How do I remove triangles and avoid pinching?

Tags: geometry

[image]Hello everyone. So I have this heart shape that I am trying to model. However, I have some triangles (example one) in the geometry that is causing pinching when I add a subdivision surface modifier (example two). Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what appears to be a planar heart that's been extruded.  My ngon version, made with a curve->curve to mesh->extrude:

[image]

If I instead grid fill that ngon, I'll get what you get.  But I'm not going to do that.  Instead, I'll inset the ngon faces ("inset faces" operation, 'i' in edit's face select mode for me,) then add a layer of subdivision and see what I get with a shiny matcap, to emphasize problems:

[image]

There are some artifacts at the edges (which is weird, and they change with applying the modifier, so it likely has something to do with my GPU and its drivers.)  Let's poke that ngon ("poke faces" operation, alt p for me,) because there's less room for ambiguity with tris than with ngons:

[image]

Okay, I'm happy with that.  And, as we add more levels of subdivision, it never shows any pinching; it improves consistently.

**For the theory of it all, for generalizing to other shapes**

Generally, for subdivision and smooth shaded normals, we have a few guidelines:

1. All faces are quads.
2. Our edge flow follows the lines of the mesh.
3. There are no places where a single vertex connects only 2 faces, and no places where a single vertex connects 6 or more faces.

All three of these are important.  We usually learn #1 first, not because it's most important, but because it's the one that's easiest to understand.  So we often make mistakes when beginning by sacrificing 2 and/or 3 for 1.  When we have to choose to break one of these rules or the other, it's a balancing act.  #1 has no special priority.  If anything has priority, it's #2.  But maybe, all of these are equal, maybe there is no priority.

To you, it probably seems like #1 is where you're getting hung up.  To me, #2 seems like where you're getting hung up.  If you select an edge loop, you'll find that your triangle terminates it.  The edge flow of your heart is a grid; it does not follow the curvature of the outline of the heart.  Whereas when we look at my mesh, the inset edge loop follows the line of the heart: *locally*, our edge flow represents the shape of the mesh.  #2 is how experienced modellers frame it, and it makes sense to them (we know it when we see it,) but there's another way to frame it, given our other rules, a little less ambiguously as two sub-guidelines:

1. All faces should be as planar as possible.
2. Anywhere that 3 faces or 5 faces meet at a single vertex, all of those faces should be as planar with each other as possible.

Now, if you look at my mesh, you'll see, hey, it's not all quads, and there's a vertex that joins a *ton* of faces.  Let's add two guidelines that make it easier to model rather than harder:

1. Whenever a face is perfectly planar with all of its neighbors, it doesn't matter whether that face is a quad.
2. Whenever all of the faces connected by a vertex are planar with each other, it doesn't matter how many faces that vertex connects.

Now, maybe you now understand that there are situations in which triangles (and ngons, if my drivers weren't broken) are okay, but the person that hired you doesn't understand that.  No problem.  Take this mesh, with triangles, and apply a single level of subdivision:

[image]

We now have an all-quad mesh, that will accept further subdivision in the exact same way.  Yes, we have a terrible pole in the middle of our face; it doesn't matter, because that pole joins only planar polys, and because if our boss isn't sophisticated enough to know that triangles are sometimes okay, they're also not sophisticated enough to know that poles are sometimes not okay.